# how to set watermark font size in mpdf

Tags: mpdf

Question is quite simple but unfortunately, i am not able to find solution.

I am trying to add watermark in pdf page. here is the code.

```
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.081;
$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Above code work fine but size of Watermark is quite big. 
I want to make it smaller.

I read the documentation but didn't found fontsize for watermark.

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/watermark-font.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the watermark fontsize by modifying `watermark` function in `mpdf.php`:

Example:

```
function watermark($texte, $angle = 45, $fontsize = 120, $alpha = 0.2) {
  $fontsize = 24
}
```