# mpdf watermark - inclined to vertical

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate a report in my project. In the report i have to place a watermark. I have placed it using some codes. But the watermark i have got it aligned as 45 degree (do know exactly how much inclined). I want it aligned vertical (90 degree).

```
$mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DUMMY');
$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.15;
```

the above code is what i used.

Does anybody know how to make it vertical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since mPDF version 7.0, this can be achieved with [`watermarkAngle`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/watermarkangle.html) configuration variable. You can either set it in the constructor

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['watermarkAngle' => 33]);
```

or you can set it as the instance property:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->watermarkAngle = 33;
```

---

Up to version 6.1.* this can be achieved only by altering mPDF source code. Somewhere along line `15724` (in version 6.1.3) in `mpdf.php` find line

```
$this->watermark($this->watermarkText, 45, 120, $this->watermarkTextAlpha);
```

and change `45` to whatever angle you want.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have been forced to use mpdf 5.7.4 bcoz it displays select box the proper way - SEE PROBLEM HERE:
[generating PDF with <SELECT> form field from HTML displays always multiline dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360151/generating-pdf-with-select-form-field-from-html-displays-always-multiline-drop)
...AND DEMO HERE:
https://osuch.com/formtools/exp/mpdfexp/project_mpdf/pdfb04_basic_active_form.php

While Finwe's solution works, I considered it not a good way to be always fumbling at the core classes each time I want a different angle. In my research I have discovered that the function watermark already provides for optional parameters to be passed to it. Say for example you want 20 degrees inclination of the watermark text, just call it like:

**$mpdf->watermark("your watermark text", 20);**

This way you need not to temper with the core classes.
My solution also solves Ironic's problem at 
[how to set watermark font size in mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369566/how-to-set-watermark-font-size-in-mpdf)
by passing the font size,

**$mpdf->watermark("your watermark text", 20, 10, 0.2);**

where 20 is your angle, 10 is your font-size, and 0.2 is your opacity.
I think this should also work in other mpdf versions where the watermark function exists.