# generating PDF with <SELECT> form field from HTML displays always multiline dropdown

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I'm using mPDF version 7.x and i need to generate PDF with fillable forms. Everything works fine except one thing - the dropdown (SELECT) always shows as with 'multiple' lines - i'm not able to create document with dropdown looking like this: https://osuch.com/formtools/exp/mpdfexp/project_mpdf/pdfb04_basic_active_form.php

my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

        //==============================================================

        $html = '
        <style>
        body
        {
            padding-bottom:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
            padding-top:0px;
        }
        h2
        {

            padding-bottom:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            margin-top:5px;
            padding-top:0px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:200%;
            color:green;
        }
        p
        {

            padding-bottom:0px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
            margin-top:10px;
            padding-top:5px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:100%;
            font-weight:normal;

        }
        .inp
        {

            padding-bottom:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            margin-top:5px;
            padding-top:0px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:100%;
            width:100%;
            border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
            background-color:#dedede;
        }
        fieldset
        {

            padding-bottom:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            margin-top:5px;
            padding-top:0px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            padding:10px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:150%;
            font-weight:bold;
            margin-top:10px;
        }

        textarea
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:100%;
            border:2px solid #000000;
            background-color: #dadada;
            background-color:#dedede;
        }

        </style>

        <body>
        <h2>Basic PDF Active Form</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>Personal Information
        <p>Name:</p>
        <div class="inp"><input type="text" size="200" name="inputname" value="" title="Enter your name"/> </div>
        <p>Company:</p>
        <div class="inp"><input type="text" size="200" name="inputco" value="" title="Company name"/> </div>
        <p>Email:</p>
        <div class="inp"><input type="text" size="200" name="inputemail" value="" title="Email address"/> </div>
        <p>Mobile:</p>
        <div class="inp"><input type="text" size="200" name="inputmobile" value="" title="Mobile telephone number"/> </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>Additional Information

        <p>How many languages do you speak?</p> 

        <input type="radio" name="num_languages" value="1" checked="checked" > One      
        <input type="radio" name="num_languages" value="2" > Two      
        <input type="radio" name="num_languages" value="3" > Three      
        <input type="radio" name="num_languages" value="4" > Four      
        <input type="radio" name="num_languages" value="5" > Five +      

        <br /><br />


        <input type="checkbox" name="email" value="email_subscrbe" checked="checked" /> Please send me regular information by e-mail<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="newsletter_subscribe" /> Please subscribe me to the Newsletter

           <p>Seminar Information</p> 
          <label for="reg_seminar">Seminar</label>
          <select size="1" name="reg_seminar" id="reg_seminar">
            <option value="Guitar for Beginners" >Guitar for Beginners</option>
            <option value="JavaScript Today" >JavaScript Today</option>
            <option value="Time is on our side" >Time is on our side</option>
          </select>

          <label for="reg_location">Location</label>
          <select size="0" name="reg_location" id="reg_location">
            <option value="New York" >New York</option>
            <option value="Paris" >Paris</option>
            <option value="Munich" >Munich</option>
            <option value="Gartmorn" >Gartmorn</option>
          </select>

          <p>Payment Type</p>
           <label><input type="radio" name="regpay" id="reg_payment01" value="Voucher" >
        Voucher</label>

           <label><input type="radio" name="regpay" id="reg_payment02" value="Cash" >
         Cash</label>

           <label><input type="radio" name="regpay" id="reg_payment03" value="CreditCard" >
         Credit Card</label>

           <label><input type="radio" name="regpay" id="reg_payment04" value="BitCoin" >
         BitCoin</label>

          <p>Comments:</p>
        <textarea name="textareafield"  rows="4" cols="80" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
          </fieldset>

        </form>
        ';
        //==============================================================
    $mpdf->useActiveForms = true;
    /*
        $mpdf->formUseZapD = false;
        $mpdf->form_border_color = '0.6 0.6 0.72';
        $mpdf->form_button_border_width = '2';
        $mpdf->form_button_border_style = 'S';
        $mpdf->form_radio_color = '0.0 0.0 0.4';    // radio and checkbox
    $mpdf->form_radio_background_color = '0.9 0.9 0.9';
     */
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        // OUTPUT
        $mpdf->Output('test.pdf'); exit;

        //==============================================================
?>
```

my output:

[image: my PDF does not reflect any CSS formatting, size attribute, nothing]

mpdf is loaded by composer, latest version. the code is taken from samples distributed with mpdf.
"missing" HTML, HEADER tags has no effect to the result.

my output PDF does not reflect any CSS formatting, "size" attribute, styling, nothing.

has anyone previously encountered this problem? (and found a solution?)

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd first try to include `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` tags and put the styles inside `<head></head>`.

Comment: Can't reproduce, Chrome 79 Windows 8.1. I see select as a dropdown not as a list

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for your hint, but as i mentioned in the post, this has no effect to the output. I tried already.

Comment: @ZohirSalak forgot to mention - i'm operation on Linux (debian 9), chrome 77. but it has no effect either - if I save the generated PDF to a file and then open it using browser (with PDF plugin) or PDF reader (Evince on Linux, Adobe Acrobat on windows), the SELECT is always shown as a list. But thanks for you reproduction, it points to some kind of local problem then a bug in mpdf library.

Comment: Darn it, I thought for sure that that would have made a difference. Well, all I can add here is to see what the HTML source looks like and the developer tools in your browser. It's hard for me to say why it's failing since I haven't done CSS using an external library before.

Answer (score 1):

got it :) seems like i'm not first and the only one who's got the same issue. 
this is solution (workaround) that helped me out: 
https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/852#issuecomment-546851163